# Phonegap and Asp.NET WebApi EF DB First

Tags: entity-framework, cordova, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

Has anyone converted a webapp designed using webApi?

I am hoping to develop an a mobile targeted webapp using webAPI (web services returning json) on Azure using EF DB first
and at a later date convert it using phonegap.

I know phonegap only takes html pages so what about cshtml pages? 
will this cause a problem at a later date?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you building a mobile app, you can develop your front end using a JS framework like jQuery Mobile/ Kendo UI etc (your files will be .html, .css and .js only) . Now this front end can easily talk to your Web API using JS/jQuery.

If you need a website and a mobile app, its better to have different UI layer(MVC for Web and HTML for Mobile) unless you are going to implement a very complex responsive design. For website you can also look for a Single Page Application(SPA) architecture.

Comment: thanks @Whizkid747, yes there is a mobile part and website part to the application. I have used MVC and would like to use it again but i am thinking there is no point in writing the functionality twice so maybe writing it all in HTML/CSS/Js for the frontend will allow me to access the WEBapi from web and mobile and also allow an easy port to native wrapped code at a later date via Phonegap

Comment: Yes pure html is the way to go.

Comment: Is it possible to use ASP.NET MVC (without using RAZOR) and then grapping the compiled HTML output (to make it easier to develop) and use that for PhoneGap?

Comment: Technically any html will run on phonegap. But iwud recommend against it. Javascript ui frameworks like Kendo UI has everything u need to build full blown mobile apps. So why bother abt MVC ? :)